# iPhone restarted when I add multiple local notification more than 1000

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, nscalendar, ekevent

In my calendar based app , I create the local notification for all event from my app also.

On every launch I remove all notification and create for 2 years. so, its above 1000 event is there.

When local notification creation device memory goes to 80 MB high. but without creation my app using 75 only and also **Energy usage very high**
device produce heat and automatically restarted on every time, so even I can't get crash log also.

I receive log :

***XPC connection interrupted
[Common] Terminating since there is no system app.***

Notes : My app minimum IOS is : iOS 9. 
        Create notification on nsoperation only.
Advanced thanks for your help.

```
    -(void)addLocalNotifiction:(EKEvent*)event andType:(NSString *)eventType andBody:(NSString*)body  {

       @autoreleasepool {
        UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

        NSDictionary *infoDict = @{@"identifier"            :   event.eventIdentifier ?: @"",
                                   @"calendarIdentifier"    :   event.calendar.calendarIdentifier ?: @"",
                                   @"date"                  :   event.startDate ?: @"",
                                   @"type"                  :   eventType,
                                   @"mode"                  :   @"new"};
        localNotification.alertBody = body;
        localNotification.userInfo = infoDict;
        localNotification.fireDate = event.alarms[0].absoluteDate;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
      }
}
```

I'll call above function on loop.

Comment: as per apple document we can schedule max 64 notification pertime,

Comment: Each app on a device is limited to 64 scheduled local notifications. The system discards scheduled notifications in excess of this limit, keeping only the 64 notifications that will fire the soonest. Recurring notifications are treated as a single notification. - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW1

Comment: Are you expecting your users to not use your app for two years? :-o

Comment: Since it's a calendar app and you are adding tasks you can set an Alert for each task and avoid all these local notifications.